# Parametrisation of surface

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Let $K= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z,\,\,  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$.

I need a parametrisation of $K$ in order to calculate the flux of some function through $K$. I'm not sure how to do it but maybe spherical coordinates will help. (they certainly help in visualising)

Switching to spherical coordinates, let's put
$$ \qquad x=r \cos \theta \sin \varphi,  \quad y=r \cos \theta \sin \varphi,  \quad z = r \cos \varphi$$

where $r \in (0,\infty), \, \theta \in (0,2\pi), \, \varphi \in (0,\pi).$

Then
$$(x,y,z)\in K \iff r=1, \quad\theta \in (0,2 \pi), \quad \varphi \in (0,\pi/4).$$

Please help me find a parametrisation of $K$.

Comment: This is a spherical cap. You can just use the spherical coordinates $\theta, \varphi$. The condition $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le z$ tells you what range of $\varphi$ to use, as you already did. The surface will be parametrized over a rectangle. Or you can use $x,y$ for the parametrization. Then the surface will be parametrized over a disk in the $x,y$ plane. The two parametrizations are related just like polar coordinates and cartesian coordinates are related in the plane.

Comment: thanks. what will our function be if we use $x,y$ for the parametrisation?

Comment: Solve the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ for $z$. The parametrization is $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,z)$.

Comment: what about the condition that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z$?

Comment: This condition leads to a restriction for $x$ and $y$ since you also know that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

Comment: ok. if we use spherical coordinates, do we get the following map: $$\Phi(\theta, \varphi) = (\cos \theta \sin \varphi, \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \cos \varphi)$$ with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $\varphi \in [0, \pi/4)$ ??

Comment: That looks right :)